# Calculate the rate of change of the slope of a tangent line of a graph, given the equation, value of x, and rate of change of x.

Tags: calculus

Here is the full question from Supp. problem 20.26, Beginning Calculus, Schaum's Outlines, 3rd. ed.

> An object is moving along the graph of $y = 3x - x^2$, and its x-coordinate is changing at the rate of two units per second. How fast is the slope of the tangent line to the graph changing when x = -1?

Here's what I've done.

given:
$y = 3x - x^2$
$\frac{dx}{dt} = 2$
$x = - 1$

1. The slope of the tangent line:
   $y' = \frac{dy}{dx} =  3 - 2x $
2. Differentiate with respect to $t$:
   $\frac{dy'}{dt} = 2\frac{dx}{dt}$
3. Substitute:
   $2(2) = 4$
4. Check answer at back of book:
   It's $12$.
5. Slap forehead.
6. Try again. Differentiate the whole first equation wrt $t$:
   $\frac{d}{dt}y = 3x - x^2 => \frac{dy}{dt} = 3\frac{dx}{dt} - 2x\frac{dx}{dt}$
7. Substitute:
   $\frac{dy}{dt} = 3(2) - 2(-1)(2) = 10$
8. Check answer at back of book:
   It's still $12$. (And honestly, what I did above was $\frac{dy}{dt}$, so it's not even *pretending* to be correct.
9. Panic. Pull hair out.  Try various other ways of creatively generating numbers other than $12$.

Honestly, the solution in 3. *seems* like it should be correct. I have the equation for the slope, $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and I've differentiated wrt $t$, which should give me the rate of change of the slope wrt time. But apparently it doesn't. I also note that my solution is independent of the value of $x$ at a given time.

So, gang, where am I going astray?

Comment: It may not be the only mistake, but you dropped a sign in step 2.

Comment: Indeed, I did. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a misprint in the question and the graph should actually be $y=3x-x^3$.

Your first attempt was actually correct for the question as printed, but note that you did not need to use the given condition $x=-1$ and this is what leads me to believe that the expression for the rate of change of the tangent gradient must have involved $x$ in some way so the question was therefore printed incorrectly...

Anyway you would get the answer in the back of the book with this expression for $y$.

Comment: Thanks, David. There is definitely a misprint in an exercise on the opposing page. And this is the only problem in this section that has caused me grief, so I think you're right. I didn't quite have enough confidence in my skills with related rates problems to invoke "misprint."  Thanks for your help. :D

Comment: You're welcome, Adam. if you want to accept the answer, please do so, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered